# Can I control network traffic or bandwidth using router?

Tags: wifi, firewalls, router, internet

That's the question I have access to the **Arris** router of a lan there are several options like DMZ, UPNP, Firewall and others. *I want get a more large bandwidth of my internet for faster download on my WI-FI* so, is there a way I can redirect the *network data traffic* or *internet bandwidth* to a predetermined computer, and how should I do it?

Comment: Many routers have a feature called "Bandwidth Limiting" or "Traffic Shaping" that you can set up to limit how much bandwidth each device on the network is allowed to use. However, there is no way for us to tell you whether your particular router has that feature because you did not include enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question could be better answered in other page because this is focused on security. Anyway...

Usually home routers don't have that feature. Usually they have QoS, but is not the same "QoS control" than "Bandwith control". Is a very different feature. You can read about them in this [article](http://blog.dlink.com/traffic-shaping-vs-quality-of-service/) for example.

- In the field of computer networking and other packet-switched telecommunication networks, **Quality of Service** refers to traffic prioritization and resource reservation control mechanisms rather than the achieved service quality. Quality of service is the ability to provide different priority to different applications, users, or data flows, or to guarantee a certain level of performance to a data flow.
- Traffic shaping (also known as **Bandwith control**) is a computer network traffic management technique which delays some or all datagrams to bring them into compliance with a desired traffic profile. Traffic shaping is used to optimize or guarantee performance, improve latency, and/or increase usable bandwidth for some kinds of packets by delaying other kinds. It is often confused with traffic policing, the distinct but related practice of packet dropping and packet marking.

I did it time ago at home using custom firmware. There are some custom firmwares like [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) which have these features. In my case installed tomato firmware and worked like a charm reserving some bandwith for playing a game while watching youtube's videos without increasing latency. Of course these firmwares are compatible with a limited hardware. Can't be placed on any router. Check out the compatibilities lists on their pages.

Good luck!